# Facebook error: SERVER_ERROR: [code] 1675030 [message]: Query error. [Extra]: null

Tags: facebook, ionic-framework

I am using Ionic 3 and cordova-plugin-facebook4, but when the Facebook provider method login is executed (@ ionic / native) error is returned -> Facebook error: SERVER_ERROR: [code] 1675030 [message]: Query error . [Extra]: null.

```
CODE:
  facebookLogin() {
    this.facebook.login(['public_profile', 'email'])
    .then((res: FacebookLoginResponse) => console.log('Logged into Facebook!', res))
    .catch(e => console.log('Error logging into Facebook', e));
  }
```

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the exact same problem.